# Conditionally change image on a button based on value changing in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, button

**IN HTML FILE:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <button id="btnStatus" title="Status">
                 <img src='images/statDisable.jpg' id=”btnImg”/>
             </button>
         </td>
         <td>
             <label>Price</label>
             <input type="text" id="tbPrice" style="width: 60px"/>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**IN JS FILE:**
   /* tries to insure that button image is set to default of disabled and 
      tries to change button image when value in price field is changed. */

```
this.init = function(){
   document.getElementById("btnImg ").src='images/statDisable.jpg';
};

$("#tbPrice").blur(function() {
   var price = $("#tbPrice").val();
   if(isNumber(price) || price > 0){
      document.getElementById("btnImg ").src='images/statEnable.jpg';

     /* also tried but did not work
        var img = $('# btnImg), a=img.parent('a');
        var srcVar = 'images/statEnable.jpg';
        img.attr({src:srcVar});
        a.attr("href", srcVar);
     */
  }
});
```

**PROBLEM:**
When user enters a numeric value greater than zero in tbPrice, I want to change the img on the btnStatus to 'images/statEnable.jpg’. I get the change event for price but can’t get image on button to change. Examples I tried just produce a button with an “X”

Comment: Where did those fancy quotes around `btnImg` come from? Also, you probably don't want a space a the end of your `getElementById` argument. Also, it seems you mean to check `isNumber(price)` AND (`&&`) `price > 0`, rather than "or" (`||`).

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the function in a doc ready, changed the isNumber to jQuery isNumeric, and changed the || to &&.  I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
this.init = function(){
   document.getElementById("btnImg ").src='images/statDisable.jpg';
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tbPrice").blur(function() {
    var price = $("#tbPrice").val();
    if($.isNumeric(price) && price > 0){
        document.getElementById("btnImg").src='images/statEnable.jpg';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("btnImg").src='images/statDisabled.jpg';
    }
  });
});
```

It changes the image if the value is numeric and positive.  For good measure it also changes it back to disabled if the value is bad.